# Copy HTML content into Excel by Java

Tags: java, html, excel

I am a Java beginner and it would be grateful if you could help to provide some sample codes or guidelines for below situation

I have a large number of html files, each file contains some school's info. Each html file may locate at different hierarchy of folder path but for sure it is always in the lowest level of the folder path. And some folders may have no school html files

For example

> C:\schools\england\london\hampstead\school_A.html [1 html in 1 folder]
>
> C:\schools\england\london\southwark\school_B.html [multiple files in 1 folder]
>
> C:\schools\england\london\southwark\school_C.html
>
> C:\schools\england\london\southwark\school_D.html
>
> C:\schools\wales\monmouth\school_E.html   [file at different path level]
>
> C:\schools\scotland\aberdeen\aberdeen     [folder has no file]

- HTML CONTENT TO BE COPIED

  ```
  < h1 id="MainControl_CustomFunctionality_ZoneMain_EmbeddedUserControlPlaceholderControl1_ctl01_schoolName" class="schoolName">**school_A**</h1>

  < li id="MainControl_CustomFunctionality_ZoneMain_EmbeddedUserControlPlaceholderControl1_ctl01_boardingTypeContainer" style="list-style: none;"><span>Day/boarding type:</span> <span id="MainControl_CustomFunctionality_ZoneMain_EmbeddedUserControlPlaceholderControl1_ctl01_boardingType" class="infoDetail">**Day, full boarding and weekly boarding**</span></li>

  < li id="MainControl_CustomFunctionality_ZoneMain_EmbeddedUserControlPlaceholderControl1_ctl01_boardingFeeContainer" style="list-style: none;"><span>Boarding fees per term:</span> <span id="MainControl_CustomFunctionality_ZoneMain_EmbeddedUserControlPlaceholderControl1_ctl01_boardingFee" class="infoDetail">**&#163;7,317 to &#163;8,370**</span></li>
  ```
- EXPECTED RESULTS IN EXCEL TABLE

3 Columns Headers: "SCHOOL"  "BOARDING TYPE"  "BOARDING FEES PER TERM"

```
Row 1: "**school_A**" "**Day,full boarding and weekly boarding**"   "**£7,317 to £8,370**"
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why are beginners given such weird tasks?

Answer (score 2):

I have some code for this requirement. Please follow this according to your requirement.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class HTMLToExcel 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

     BufferedReader br = null;

     try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:\\Excels\\log_km_styles1.html")));

        // Create Work book
          XSSFWorkbook xwork = new XSSFWorkbook();

          // Create Spread Sheet
          XSSFSheet xsheet = xwork.createSheet("MyFristSheet");

          //Create Row (Row is inside spread sheet)
          XSSFRow xrow  = null;

          int rowid =0;
          String line ;
          while (( line =br.readLine())!= null) {



            // Create font for applying bold or italic or same thing else on the content
            /*XSSFFont xfont = xwork.createFont();
            xfont.setBoldweight(xfont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

            XSSFCellStyle xstyle = xwork.createCellStyle();
            xstyle.setFont(xfont);*/

             System.out.println(line);

             String split[] = line.split("<br>");
             Cell cell;
             for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                 xrow = xsheet.createRow(rowid);
                 cell = xrow.createCell(2);
                 cell.setCellValue(split[i]);
                 String[] columnSplit = split[i].split("\\W+");
                 int columnCount = 3;
                 for (int j = 0; j < columnSplit.length; j++) {

                     cell = xrow.createCell(columnCount++);
                     cell.setCellValue(columnSplit[j]);
                }
                System.out.println(split[i]);
                rowid++;
            }





          } 


        // create date for adding this to our workbook name like workbookname_date
            Date d1 = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
            String todaysDate = sdf.format(d1);
            System.out.println(sdf.format(d1));
            //Create file system using specific name
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Excels\\redaingfromHTMLFile_"+todaysDate+".xlsx"));

            xwork.write(fout);
            fout.close();
            System.out.println("redaingfromHTMLFile_"+todaysDate+".xlsx written successfully" );
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Above code converts html file content into Excel file. It will create new file with today's date in the file name. try with this one. I hope it will help you

Comment: Did you tried with this code? If you need more information please let me know